# arc length, problems to find the limits for t

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

How do I find the limits for t?

(a) Let $C$ be the parametric curve
$$r(t) = \frac{t^3}{3}\hat i + t^2\hat j + 2t \hat k$$
Determine the arc length of $C$ between the points $(0, 0, 0)$ and $( 1/3, 1, 2)$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: $t=0$ gives the first point, and $t=1$ gives the second. (I'm assuming there is a missing exponent in the j-component.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$\int\sqrt(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2) dt$

= $\int\sqrt(t^2+2t+2) dt$
=$\int\sqrt((t+1)^2+1)dt$

let $t+1=Sinhu$ and use substitution method

between t=0 and t=1

Answer (score 0):

You find the limits by solving for $t$ for any of the three values (beginning or ending, $\hat i$ or $\hat j$ or $\hat k$). It is easiest here to use the $\hat k$ coefficients, so the starting $t$ is where
$$2t=0$$
and the ending is where
$$2t=2$$

This means the limits are $0$ and $1$.

We find arc length by
$$\int_0^1 {\sqrt {{{\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dt}}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {\frac{{dz}}{{dt}}} \right)}^2}} \;dt} $$
$$=\int_0^1 {\sqrt {\left(t^2 \right)^2 + \left(2t \right)^2 + \left(2 \right)^2} \;dt} $$
$$=\int_0^1 {\sqrt {t^4 + 4t^2 + 4} \;dt}$$
$$=\int_0^1 {\sqrt {\left(t^2 + 2 \right)^2} \;dt}$$
$$=\int_0^1 {\left(t^2 + 2 \right) \;dt}$$

I assume you can finish it from here.